# Android Array Adaptor - insert a checkbox into each row

Tags: android, arrays, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

Right so, I have a navbar layout.  The `<FrameLayout>` in content_main is replaced with stand1.xml when the stand1 button in my navbar is pressed. This works without any issue.

Content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

stand1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Stand1list">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

from main activity

```
if (id == R.id.Stand1) {
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new Stand1()).commit();
    setTitle(R.string.Stand1);
```

Following tutorials online this is my Stand1.java file which is used to populate the a list with a array of strings

```
public class Stand1 extends Fragment {
    ListView mList;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stand1,container,false);
        mList = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.Stand1list);
        return root;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        populateListView();
    }

    private void populateListView() {
        String[] pair = {"Pair1","Pair2","Pair3","Pair4","Pair5"};

        //build adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.row_layout,pair);

        mList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

and row_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

This is working, It displays the 5 strings. However i want to make it so i can also have a check box in each row.
If i try place `linear layout` in row_layout.xml , i get error

```
ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

I was following stackoverflow which sorted other errors which suggested that i had to make the list at class level and inflate it in onCreate.

I know i prob have to make an custom array adapter, but my problem is how do i deal with the inflation of the view in the on create.

**Im not really sure how i go about doing this. So can somebody tell me from here, how do i go about having a check box in each row.**

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter` needs to know where to put the text from your string array. By default, it assumes the layout you pass it is a `TextView` and will set its text to one of the strings. If you pass it a more complicated layout, you need to tell it the id of the `TextView` you want it to use. You can do that with [this constructor](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T[]%29).